# CodeMirror TextArea not rendering as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, codemirror

I am using CodeMirror in my application to allow code editing. I have the following page code:

```
@model Tarantula.Models.NewDiscussionModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/codemiror/lib/codemirror.css".>
<script src="/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="/codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Title);
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Body);
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Body);
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}

<script>
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("Body"), {
  lineNumbers: false
});
</script>
```

Model:

```
public class NewDiscussionModel 
{ 
    [DataType(DataType.Text)] 
    [Required] 
    [Display(Name="Title")] 
    public string Title; 

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)] 
    [Required] 
    [Display(Name="Message")] 
    public string Body; 
}
```

Unfortunately the text area is not rending correctly. I just get an empty space where the text area should be. What am I doing wrong? I'm very new to CodeMirror.

Thanks, Mark

Comment: Could you post your model?

Comment: Sure. Here's my model
    
    public class NewDiscussionModel
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Title")]
        public string Title;

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Message")]
        public string Body;
    }

Comment: Try to change Body to another name! Looks like something is mismatching the Body from the model propertie with something in the HTML, maybe the tag Body itself!

Comment: I changed my text area id to Message but the same problem exists. Any more ideas?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I would be helpful